# How to get id of clicked element based on its class jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using the code below to create a simple lightbox effect, but the id of the clicked item returns empty

jquery:

```
function openBigImage(){
    var id = this.id;
    var contenti = "#"+id;
    $(contenti).css("display", "block");
    alert(contenti);
    $(contenti).animate({
            left: "-=448px",
            width: "+=896px",
            top: "-=227px",
            height: "+=454px",
            padding:"+=10px"
            }, 400 );
    $("body").prepend( "<div id='erresira'></div>" );
    $("#close").css("display", "block");
};
```

html/php:

```
<span  class="link">
                <h4> <?php echo substr($item->title, 0, 12); ?> </h4>
                <div class="cont"> 
                    <span>Guarda il profilo></span> 
                </div>
            </span> 
            <div id="contenti<?=$item->id;?>" class="contenti" >
                <strong><?php echo substr($item->title, 0, 12); ?></strong> 
                <strong><p class="mod-articles-category-introtext"> <?php echo $item->displayIntrotext; ?> </p></strong> 
            </div>
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: How do you call `openBigImage()`? Where is the click handler???

Comment: $(".link").click(openBigImage);

I place this in the begining of the code

Comment: link class didn't have no id

Comment: you mean `$(".link").click(openBigImage());` ?

Comment: lsafdkflösad.attr('id')

Comment: So it should be: `var id =  $(this).next('.contenti')[0].id;`. FYI, your HTML markup is invalid, DIV shouldn't be child of SPAN

Comment: well, no. 
    $(".link").click(openBigImage); seems to work.

Comment: <span  class="link"> it has no id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<span class="link">` has no id attribute.

You don't need its ID to get the jquery object:

`$(this)` (assuming you don't change the click handlers context)

`$(event.currentTarget)` (assuming you do)

i.e.

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
     $(this).someJQueryFunction();
     $(e.currentTarget).someJQueryFunction();
});
```